# Joomla 2.5 Show subcategory image on blog view

Tags: image, joomla2.5, categories

I am having trouble showing the image of a subcategory on my blogview.

Furthest I've gotten is showing the image of the parent category with this line:

```
$this->category->getParams()->get('image');
```

This line shows the title of the subcategory though

```
$this->escape($this->item->category_title);
```

So I've tried adding `item` in that top line but it didn't take. My knowledge of Joomla and php isn't enough to figure out how to change this to show the subcategory image instead.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** 
To elaborate, the blog view I am using is a view of all the articles in the category 'Trends'. The category Trends however does not include any articles but all of it's subcategories do.

So the structure is as follows:

- -Trends
- --Trend1
- ---Article1
- ----Article2
- ---Trend2
- ---Article1
- ---Article2

With this blog I want to show the image of the subcategory that the article is related to. In the Joomla parameters I set the option to show the category image, however this only shows the parent category image not the subcategory image.

Comment: Which file are you editing?

Comment: I've made a template override for the blog files. The file I am editting is blog_item.php (Original location: com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_item.php)

Comment: OK, as I can see the children category titles are stored in a protected variable which is not accessible in template. I can only think of a one solution right now, which is to use a module. I'll look for it and if there wasn't, you should write it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

There's no need to change the code for that.

When you are seeing "$this->category->**getParams()**->get('image');" in the code, it means that the template is reading parameters to whether show the image or not.

You can change the global parameters of `com_content` with `Option` button in top-right of your administrator interface, or you can change a specific category's parameters in `Edit Category` mode.

I can see a `Category Image` parameter there!

**Solution 2:**

Use `print_r` to see all the attributes of `item`, like this: `print_r($this->item)`, then you will see if the `item` has something like `category_image` or not. If it contains image, use it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

I've already looked at the parameters. I can set the category image to show, but this is not what I want. I want to show the image for the subcategory. The code '$this->category->getParams()->get('image');' gives me the image path of the (parent) category image which I can then use to show the image. I've tried the print_r but I can't seem to find anything relating to the image of a subcategory.

Answer (score 0):

I made it by creating a new instance of JCategories by catid. And then I took an image from it by getParams().

```
$options    = array();
$categories = JCategories::getInstance('Content', $options);
$category   = $categories->get($this->item->catid);

<img src="<?php echo $category->getParams()->get('image'); ?>"/>
```